# TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted using Xpath through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

Part of page source:

```
<span style="display:block; overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap">Gi2/0/20</span>
```

Parts of the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
...
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
...
IP_CLICK = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@style="display:block; overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap"]/text()="Gi2/0/20"').click()
```

I am trying to select an element in my web page with the `xpath` expression, but I'm getting the following error:

```
InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //span[@style="display:block; overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap"]/text()="Gi2/0/20" because of the following error:
```

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.
>   (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.20 (8e2b610813e167eee3619ac4ce6e42e3ec622017),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: Take a few minutes to properly format your question so that the HTML and code is formatted as code and the error is formatted as a quote. It makes the question a LOT easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the invalid xpath expression, use the below modified xpath :

```
IP_CLICK = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Gi2/0/20']");
IP_CLICK.click();
```

If there are multiple matches then use the indexing, I mean pass the matching index number in the below xpath :

```
xpath = "(//span[text()='Gi2/0/20'])[Matching index number goes here]";
IP_CLICK = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath);
IP_CLICK.click();
```

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type. 
 (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121) (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.20 (8e2b610813e167eee3619ac4ce6e42e3ec622017),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

...implies that the result of executing the *xpath* expression was not a node set.

Syntactically, the *xpath* expression you have used is a **legit** *xpath* expression which uses the `text()` node as in **`parent_element/text()="Gi2/0/20"`** following [xpath v3.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html).

Unfortunately *Selenium* implements [xpath v1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) which doesn't supports `text()` nodes.

Additionally, `click()` doesn't returns anything, so `IP_CLICK` is not needed.

### Solution

To `click()` on the element, you can use either of the following solutions:

- *Xpath 1*:

  ```
  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Gi2/0/20']").click()
  ```
- *Xpath 2*:

  ```
  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(., 'Gi2/0/20')]").click()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath should be:

```
//span[@style="display:block; overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap" and text()="Gi2/0/20"]
```

It will look for `span` element matching the `@style` and `text()` values.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you can not use a text node in selenium to locate an element 
e.g. `//span/text()`

You have to find an alternative to locate the element something like this

```
//span[contains(.,'matching_text')]
```

OR

```
//span[text()='exact _text')]
```

There is an alternative to locate the element using text not i.e javascriptexecutor

Here is java sample code

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Object message = js.executeScript("var value = document.evaluate(\"//p[@class='artdeco-toast-message']/node()[not(self::button)]\",document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null ); return value.stringValue;");
System.out.println(message.toString().trim());
```

Refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) link for more